# Sass ampersand, select immmediate parent?

Tags: sass

Is there a way in Sass to use the ampersand to select the immediate parent, rather than the parent selector of the entire group? For example:

```
.wrapper{
    background-color: $colour_nav_bg;
    h1{
        color: $colour_inactive;
        .active &{
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

compiles to:

```
.wrapper h1{
    color: grey;
}

.active .wrapper h1{
    color: red
}
```

but what I actually want is:

```
.wrapper .active h1{
    color: red;
}
```

Is the only option to write the SCSS like so?

```
.wrapper{
    background-color: $colour_nav_bg;
    h1{
        color: $colour_inactive;
    }
    .active h1{
        color: red;
    }
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="wrapper">
    <li class="active">
        <h1>blah</h1>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't think so there is another option left for same, U had solution within your question itself :)

Comment: It just seems nicer to have the active state nested within the h1 though so thought I'd ask. Thanks

Comment: yes, that can be solution. I thought you just want SASS solution with existing HTML :)anyway- caryy on

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of this writing, there is no Sass selector for the direct parent instead of the root parent of an element.  There is `&` which (as you know) selects the root parent.  There are also `%` [placeholder selectors](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_) which hides a rule until it's been [extended](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend).

Sass is [open-sourced](http://sass-lang.com/development.html), so you could contribute a new "direct parent" selector.

Comment: Has this changed at all now that we have SASS 3.3?

Comment: v3.3 adds the @at-root selector, which compiles to the root parent selector. `@at-root .active & { color: red; }` is close (compiling to `.active .wrapper h1 { color: red; }`, but not quite what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Has this still not been implemented?

Answer (score 12):

You can work around this today with a mixin like this one:

```
@mixin if-direct-parent($parent-selector) {
  $current-sequences: &;
  $new-sequences: ();

  @each $sequence in $current-sequences {
    $current-selector: nth($sequence, -1);
    $prepended-selector: join($parent-selector, $current-selector);
    $new-sequence: set-nth($sequence, -1, $prepended-selector);
    $new-sequences: append($new-sequences, $new-sequence, comma);
  }

  @at-root #{$new-sequences} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Since the `&` is essentially a list of lists, you can use list functions ([nth](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method), [set-nth](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#set_nth-instance_method), [join](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#join-instance_method) and [append](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#append-instance_method)) to create the selector sequence you want. Then use `@at-root` to output the new selector at root-level. Here's how you'd use it:

```
.grandparent-1,
.grandparent-2 {
  color: red;

  .child {
    color: blue;

    @include if-direct-parent('.parent') {
      color: green;
    }
  }
}
```

Which will output:

```
.grandparent-1,
.grandparent-2 {
  color: red;
}
.grandparent-1 .child,
.grandparent-2 .child {
  color: blue;
}
.grandparent-1 .parent .child, .grandparent-2 .parent .child {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use multiple parent classes (because in my case I have several parent classes on which I would have to apply this mixin?

Comment: @KarlRegensburger yes, you can do: `@include if-direct-parent('.parent-1 .parent-2 .parent-3') { ... }` and that should result in something like this: `.grandparent .parent-1 .parent-2 .parent-3 .child { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap @at-root content in {}

```
.wrapper {
    h1 {
        @at-root {
           .wrapper .active h1 {
                color: red;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `@at-root` basically unnests the rules, so you might've as well not put the rules in the parent at all and would achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Just a variation on @myajouri's answer.

@KarlRegensburger asked in the comments if it's possible to use multiple parent selectors. This can be done by changing the $parent-selector parameter to a list, and using another @each rule to loop over it, like so:

```
@mixin if-direct-parent($parent-selectors) {
    $current-sequences: &;
    $new-sequences: ();

    @each $parent-selector in $parent-selectors {
        @each $sequence in $current-sequences {
            $current-selector: nth($sequence, -1);
            $prepended-selector: join($parent-selector, $current-selector);
            $new-sequence: set-nth($sequence, -1, $prepended-selector);
            $new-sequences: append($new-sequences, $new-sequence, comma);
        }
    }

    @at-root #{$new-sequences} {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Now, you can include either a single selector as before, or a list of selectors:

```
.grandparent {
  color: red;

  .child {
    color: blue;

    @include if-direct-parent([.parent-1, .parent-2, .parent-3]) {
      color: green;
    }
  }
}
```

Will give:

```
.grandparent {
  color: red;
}
.grandparent .child {
  color: blue;
}
.grandparent .parent-1 .child, .grandparent .parent-2 .child, .grandparent .parent-3 .child {
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In "Neil Haskins" Answer which allow to pass array of parent selectors, the args should be passed like this:

```
@include if-direct-parent((".parent-1", ".parent-2", ".parent-3")) {
    color: green;
}
```

`[.parent-1, .parent-2, .parent-3]` gives error.

Answer (score -1):

I have often wanted to do what you're asking and its a no go. I heard you can do that sort of thing in Stylus however. But there is another thing you can try which is to use `@at-root` to teleport outside of your nesting tree. For instance:

```
.wrapper{
    h1{
        @at-root .wrapper .active h1 {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

This should compile down to the following:

```
.wrapper .active h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

The nice part is you keep your selector where it logically makes sense in the nesting structure for organizational purposes.