# Referencing direct parent with & and not absolute parent

Tags: sass

**For this SASS:**

```
@mixin sameHeight($multiplier){
    height:367px + 21px * $multiplier;
}

.page{
  .inner{
    @for $i from 1 through 3{
       .compare-#{$i} &{ @include sameHeight($i); };
    }
  }
}
```

**I get this:**

```
.compare-1 .page .inner {
  height: 215px;
}
.compare-2 .page .inner {
  height: 250px;
}
.compare-3 .page .inner {
  height: 285px;
}
```

### But I would like this:

```
.page .compare-1 .inner {
  height: 215px;
}
.page .compare-2 .inner {
  height: 250px;
}
.page .compare-3 .inner {
  height: 285px;
}
```

Basically the `&` is just adding the `compare` class to the absolute top-most parent, which is not something I want to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ampersand (`&`) is a **placeholder for the whole path of parent selectors** of a nested rule (in your case `.page .inner`). So it will always insert all nested selectors/levels above wherever it is placed in a nested selector and [**not just the immediate parent**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833674/sass-ampersand-select-immmediate-parent).

Here is a good [**article with some examples**](http://www.joeloliveira.com/2011/06/28/the-ampersand-a-killer-sass-feature/) showing how to make the best use of the ampersand in Sass.

You could instead just do something like this (if `.inner` represents a child of the `.compare...` class):

```
.page{
    @for $i from 1 through 3{
       .compare-#{$i} .inner { @include sameHeight($i); };
    }
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7451286)

---

<sup>- Maybe you will find something useful in other SO Q/A on this topic aswell, see: **[[Sass] ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsass%5D+ampersand)**.</sup>
<sup>- A related [**issue on Github**](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/286).</sup>

---

#### Edit:

Since you say in the comment below that you want to apply this with a mixin - you can use an additional `compare` mixin that just constructs the selectors around the `.inner` content, where you can then add your `sameHeight` property. Something along these lines:

```
@mixin compare {
  @for $i from 1 through 3 {
    .compare-#{$i} {
      $m: $i;
      @content;
    }
  }
} $m: 0;

.page{
  @include compare {
    .inner {
      @include sameHeight($m);
    }
  }
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7458493)

You could alternatively use the `.compare...` and `.inner` classes on the same element/tag, which would eliminate the problem with the second level of nesting ([DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7458629)). Or instead of using nested rules you could construct the hierarchical selectors from variables (you can even save the `&` value in a variable - [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7458758)). All depends then on your exact case (markup structure and the complete styling) that is not exactly clear to me from your example. But I hope I gave you at least some ideas in the right direction.

Comment: yes this is what I did eventually, but the thing is, I have this code in about 10 files and I wanted to use MIXIN. it's too bad we cannot control the scope of which parent to address or something of the sort.

Comment: I updated the answer with some additional ideas ... that might help you with designing the mixin or rules for your 10 files =)

Comment: SASS can get pretty crazy sometimes :) nice idea to pass the content itself and call the function.