# SASS ampersand move class to being of adjacent select, not to the parent tree

Tags: sass

I've rewritten the question to make this easier to understand.

I am using a class in my theme to control accent styles. I have a multisite using one theme so the theme is being style using my theme classes...

```
.theme-portal
.theme-motogp
.theme-mxgp
.theme-rally
```

But please note, that my theme styles change within themes.

For example, my theme class is applied to the `<BODY>` tag on every single page.

So like `<BODY class="theme-portal">` or `<BODY class="theme-motogp">` etc. But even though the body has this class `<BODY class="theme-portal">`, further down the same page the mxgp class could be applied to a table or an article, for example `<TABLE class="theme-portal">` or `<ARTICLE class="theme-motogp">`

Now I am trying to be clever and save code, I am this mixin below and control access class stylings...

```
@mixin theme-change($theme) {
    .theme-#{$theme} & {
        @content;
    }
}
```

And I use like this...

```
.btn {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;

    &.btn-accent {
        color: #ffffff;

        /* portal site */
        @include theme-change('portal') {
            background-color: $color-portal-red;
        }

        /* motogp site */
        @include theme-change('motogp') {
            background-color: $color-motogp-orange;
        }

        /* mxgp site */
        @include theme-change('mxgp') {
            background-color: $color-mxgp-red;
        }

        /* rally site */
        @include theme-change('rally') {
            background-color: $color-rally-red;
        }

    }

}
```

the above sass block outputs...

```
.theme-portal .btn.btn-accent { ... }
.theme-motogp .btn.btn-accent { ... }
.theme-mxgp .btn.btn-accent { ... }
.theme-rally .btn.btn-accent { ... }
```

and another nice example of my mixin working to control my theme accents

```
.header-bar-secondary {

    UL.nav {

        > LI {

            > A {

                /* portal site */
                @include theme-change('portal') {
                    color: #000000;
                    &:hover {
                        background-color: #ffffff;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }
                }

                /* motogp site */
                @include theme-change('motogp') {
                    ...
                }

                /* mxgp site */
                @include theme-change('mxgp') {
                    ...
                }

                /* rally site */
                @include theme-change('rally') {
                    ...
                }

            }

        }

    }

    /* portal site */
    @include theme-change('portal') {
        border-color: #e0e0e0;
        @include background-image(linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f2f2f2));
        ...
    }

    /* motogp site */
    @include theme-change('motogp') {
        ...
    }

    /* mxgp site */
    @include theme-change('mxgp') {
        ...
    }

    /* rally site */
    @include theme-change('rally') {
        ...
    }

}
```

the above sass block outputs...

```
.theme-portal .header-bar-secondary UL.nav > LI > A { ... }
.theme-portal .header-bar-secondary UL.nav > LI > A:hover { ... }
.theme-motogp .header-bar-secondary UL.nav > LI > A { ... }
.theme-motogp .header-bar-secondary UL.nav > LI > A:hover { ... }
.theme-mxgp .header-bar-secondary UL.nav > LI > A { ... }
.theme-mxgp .header-bar-secondary UL.nav > LI > A:hover { ... }
.theme-rally .header-bar-secondary UL.nav > LI > A { ... }
.theme-rally .header-bar-secondary UL.nav > LI > A:hover { ... }

.theme-portal .header-bar-secondary { ... }
.theme-motogp .header-bar-secondary { ... }
.theme-mxgp .header-bar-secondary { ... }
.theme-rally .header-bar-secondary { ... }
```

OK here is the problem. Using the mixing below in this block. As I described in my previous question I am trying to move the theme class to just before the element name. But my current mixin is moving the class right to the beginning of the sass block.

See sass example below where mixin fails.

```
#primary_carousel {

    .item {

        .inner {


        }

    }

    .overlay {

        H1 {

            /* portal site */
            @include theme-change('portal') {
                ...
            }

            /* motogp site */
            @include theme-change('motogp') {
                ...
            }

            /* mxgp site */
            @include theme-change('mxgp') {
                ...
            }

            /* rally site */
            @include theme-change('rally') {
                ...
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The reason it is failing is because my theme class is applied to the `<BODY class="theme-portal">` like this. But the theme class is also applied to `<DIV class="item">` which is a child of `<BODY>`

See below HTML structure...

```
<BODY class="theme-portal">

    <DIV id="primary_carousel">

        <DIV class="item theme-motogp">

            <DIV class="inner">

                <DIV class="overlay">
```

See below the above failing SASS block output...

```
.theme-portal #primary_carousel .overlay { ... }
.theme-motogp #primary_carousel .overlay { ... }
.theme-mxgp #primary_carousel .overlay { ... }
.theme-rally #primary_carousel .overlay { ... }
```

But because the my body tag has the `<BODY class="theme-portal">` applied to it, it overrides my theme class which is applied to the `<DIV class="item">`

So I need my sass to output like this somehow using a simple mixin or clever new & operator...

```
#primary_carousel .theme-portal .overlay { ... }
#primary_carousel .theme-motogp .overlay { ... }
#primary_carousel .theme-mxgp .overlay { ... }
#primary_carousel .theme-rally .overlay { ... }
```

If you can help left me know a operator that moves the class to just before the selector, rather than the beginning of the sass block that would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass ampersand, select immmediate parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833674/sass-ampersand-select-immmediate-parent)

Comment: No matter how much you edit your question, it is still a duplicate.

Comment: @cimmanon your same question does not show a clear answer with my mixin scenario - so how about some help please ;-)

Comment: The answer is "no", you can't do what you're asking for.  There is no such operator, as the question I've linked to indicates.  You have to change the order of your nesting as the answer below indicates.

Comment: @cimmanon I take it `@at-root` selector is not the same?

Comment: The `@at-root` selector will not help in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

```
#primary_carousel {

    .item {

        H1 {

        }

        & .theme-one H1{
            background: red;
        }

        & .theme-two H1{
            background: blue;
        }

    }

}
```

The ampersand in SASS/SCSS takes the place of all the parent selectors that it is nested in, not just the last one. In this case that is `#primary_carousel .item` where as in the original code provided it is nested inside the H1 so it is `#primary_carousel .item H1`. You can't put the theme classes inbetween the other classes using the ampersand, so you have to take it out of the H1 and then put your class and then the H1 after your class that is changing.

**EDIT:** Looking over the code again, I've actually just noticed that you don't even need the ampersands in this case, but I've left them in since the question is about them.

```
CSS OUTPUT:

#primary_carousel .item .theme-one H1 {
    background: red;
}
#primary_carousel .item .theme-two H1 {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Care to explain your solution or give some references?

Comment: Not sure about this as maybe it does not fix my issue. Please see above more detailed question. Which I should of done first time.

Comment: I've added the output css and it matches exactly what you are asking for in the question, so if it's not working you might either have a problem with SASS compiling or a typo somewhere in your code. If you want to put up the HTML, I can try and help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @AndrewTet rewrote my question